# If XOR of n distinct numbers is ANDed over one of the number, the result would be zero

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor

Say we Have n distinct numbers

```
x1,x2,....xn
```

And we xor the result

```
xoredResult = x1^x2...^xn
```

And if we AND(&) with one of the number say x2
We get Zero

```
xoredResult & x2 = 0
```

Can we always claim that if the ANDed result is zero that the number is repeated ?
Can this be used to find the first repeated element in a stream of numbers ?

Comment: You are saying that $(a \oplus b) \wedge b = 0$ if $a = 0$ and $b=1$ then the output is 1

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work, for example if `x2 = 0` then `xoredResult & x2 = 0` all the time no matter what else the set of numbers contains.

Or for an other example, the set `{ 1, 2, 3 }` xors to zero (so it ANDed by any of its members, or even anything else, yields zero) but contains no repeated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not.

Take x = 110, y = 101, z = 011. Every bit is set in two numbers, so r = (x xor y xor z) = 0. So x and r, y and r, z and r are all zero, with nothing repeated.

The code you linked to is something totally different. There each number occurs 3 times, except one number X which occurs once. If we count how often each bit is set, then for a bit in X the number of times it is set is 3k+1, for a bit not in X the number of times it is set is 3k times for unknown k.

The code there simulates n counters modulo 3 with bit operations. Totally different. Very clever method. Can be generalised to "for every number except at most one, the number of occurences is a (modulo b) for fixed a and b. Find the value of the one number where the number of occurences is not a (modulo b) or show there is none", running in O (n log b) time.